# Python Service Installation - "Could not find PythonClass entry"

Tags: python, windows, interop, pywin32

I am working on building a Python service. I am inducing this error, but I am not sure what is inducing it.

```
PS C:\...> python .\file.py debug
Debugging service MYSERVICE - press Ctrl+C to stop.
Error 0xC00000F4 - Could not find the service's PythonClass entry in the registry
Error 1814 - The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file.
Error 0xC0000080 - Could not locate the module name in the Python class string (ie, no '.')
```

This error is coming from PythonServiceMessages.mc in PythonWin32.

Comment: what's in file.py?  code please

Comment: What did you do to fix this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same error today. After 5 hours of trying everything the issue was that the service name had a space in it .

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this error result is caused by an exception being thrown and the Python script dying off.